# How does initialization on demand holder idiom work with parameters?

Tags: java, vert.x

[Here is the link to initialization on demand holder idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom#Example_Java_Implementation) 
I've created a class with Singleton design pattern and double locking strategy. I want to change this class to use initialization on demand holder, but I couldn't accross examples where this is parameterized.

1. How should I pass the parameters `basePath1`, `basePath2` while using initialization on demand holder pattern ?
2. Would the present code and code with initialization on demand holder pattern cause any concurrency issues ?

```
public class Api {
private String basePath1;
private String basePath2;

    private StringBuilder temporalEndpoint;
    private StringBuilder spatialEndpoint;
    private StringBuilder fileUploadEndpoint;
    private StringBuilder fileDownloadEndpoint;
    private StringBuilder fileDeleteEndpoint;
    private StringBuilder listMetaDataEndpoint;
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(Api.class);
    
    private static volatile Api apiInstance;
    
    
    
    private Api(String basePath1, String basePath2) {
        this.basePath1 = basePath1;
        this.basePath2 = basePath2;
        buildEndpoints();
    }
    
    public static Api getInstance(String basePath1, String basePath2)
    {
        if(apiInstance == null)
        {
                synchronized(Api.class)
                  {
                         if(apiInstance == null)
                          {
                                  apiInstance = new Api(basePath1, basePath2);
                            }
                 }
             }
        return apiInstance;
    }
    
    public void buildEndpoints() {
        temporalEndpoint = new StringBuilder(basePath1).append(API_TEMPORAL);
        spatialEndpoint = new StringBuilder(basePath1).append(API_SPATIAL);
        fileUploadEndpoint = new StringBuilder(basePath1).append(API_FILE_UPLOAD);
        fileDownloadEndpoint = new StringBuilder(basePath1).append(API_FILE_DOWNLOAD);
        fileDeleteEndpoint = new StringBuilder(basePath2).append(API_FILE_DELETE);
        listMetaDataEndpoint = new StringBuilder(basePath2).append(API_LIST_METADATA);
    }
```

Comment: Think about what you are doing here: if you invoke `getInstance("bp1", "bp2")`, and then `getInstance("bp3", "bp4")`, you don't get a correctly-constructed `Api` back - you get the one for the previous (first) invocation. This is simply a bad idea. There's no real need to limit the construction of these instances - they are very cheap to construct. Why do you think construction on demand (statically) is better than construction on demand (at the point of use)?

Comment: To answer your question more directly: initialization on demand does not work well/at all with parameters.

Comment: Hi @Andy Turner, thanks for suggesting! Here are multiple classes like Api class doing a single thing. So, making a lot of instances that might of these different classes, might take up some space in the memory which is not very useful.

Comment: It's far more useful to have many instances of a class than it is to (unknowingly) have one instance of a class which does the wrong thing. The memory usage of the class you have shown is basically irrelevant.